# How to run spark sql queries using Databricks Cluster through Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to execute spark sql commands from Linux Machine on Databricks Cluster. Is there any way to achieve this?
I have set of spark sql commands in a .sql file and want to execute this file using Databricks cluster in Linux Machine.
I am looking something analogous to SQLPLUS, where we make connection with DB and execute sql, in the similar way do we have any utility/solution to execute spark sql over Databricks cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a Databricks cluster using ODBC, JDBC, HTTP or thrift protocol. In every case you will need an access token with enough permissions.

I am using IntelliJ DataGrip to connect via JDBC. I had to configure the databricks driver and used this URI.

`jdbc:spark://mycompany.cloud.databricks.com:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/<MY-DATABRICKS-ORGAINZATION-ID>/<MY-DATABRICKS-CLUSTER-ID>;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=<MY-DATABRICKS-TOKEN>`

I believe any modern SQL client should be able to connect as Databricks is exposing standard interfaces.

This is the official documentation from databricks
https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html